# With hardware acceleration enabled, Android Webview gets a delay on javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, delay, hardware-acceleration

This is weird, but when I set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in Manifest, the javascript code runs normally (but CSS transitions get laggy) and when I set it to true, CSS transitions work like a charm, but javascript performance gets a 1 second delay every event triggered.

JavaScript (jQuery) code:

`$(".tile").on("click", function () { //routine called here });`

With hardware acceleration **ON**: 1 second delay before calling the routine and CSS transitions are normal.

With hardware acceleration **OFF**: no delay, normal JavaScript performance and laggy on CSS transitions (as expected)

Does anyone have a clue on this?